# PHP script: Parse error: syntax error

Tags: php

When executing the  email2mysql.php file
taken from [here](http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/topic/41225-get-contents-from-e-mail-and-write-it-to-mysql-table), I get this error message

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'stream' (T_STRING) in
>   email2mysql.php on line 73

Comment: The link is to a forum discussion - with lots of code. please tell us exactly where you got the code from - maybe the user name & date/time fo their post? But preferably an actual URL, unless it is inline on that forum.

Comment: Welcome aboard. We would like to help, but this is the wrong site. We recommend software tools here; we don't fix code. You should ask at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) At that site you always have to 1) post the code (not a link to it) 2) say what it is supposed to do 3) say what it is doing wrongly instead. For sure we will help you over there :-)

Answer (score 1):

When I get this, it is usually because I failed to put a semi-colon on the line above it.

I have also made the mistake of having quotes or apostrophes mismatched or nested incorrectly.

I have also made the mistake of allowing lines of code to flow together, where one line has "end-of-line" comments, and what was supposed to be the next line has moved to be within the scope of that comment.

I recommend a programmer's text editor that shows PHP syntax as colored letters. This will make plain any of the above errors.

I recommend UltraEdit, GitHub's Atom editor, or Notepad++.

Comment: It could also be mismatched quote.  I would ***strongly*** advise you not to use an editor - get yourself an IDE -  which Atom is ([Eclipse]9https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) is also very popular with professional developers, as is [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/features/php/). Just choose an IDE which you like, the important thing is that it lets you debug your code. You can set a "breakpoin" and the code will run until that line. Then you can examine, and even change, the values of your variables. You can see the callstack - which function called which, with what parameters ...

Comment: ... and step through the code, line by line. It is ***extremely*** difficult to develop software without using the debugger, so get started as soon as you can. It will answer most of your questions, before you even think of Stack Overflow :-)